# How to replace random number in asp.net/c with pictures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to replace random number with pictures. for example If random number is 1 show picture black.jpg:

```
Cache[diceKey] = r.Next(1, 5);  // random (1-4)

if (r.Next(1, 2) == 1 )
    image.BackImageUrl = "Images/black.png";
```

is there any solutions that I can show my picture if random number is 1?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Aside from the fact that `r.Next(1, 2)` will always return 1...

Comment: the only problem I have, I want to display black.png when random number display "1" . is it correct way to say that; if (r.Next(1,2) == 1)   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already said in my comment `r.Next(1, 2)` will **always** return 1, so you will always show that black image...

I think you should change your code to this:

```
var randomValue = r.Next(1, 5);  // random (1-4)
Cache[diceKey] = randomValue;

if (randomValue == 1)
    image.BackImageUrl = "Images/black.png";
else
    image.BackImageUrl = "";
```

Comment: it gave's me an error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and int . Cache[diceKey] is a type of object

Answer (score 6):

Store your image urls in an array. Generate a random index to access the image:

```
string[] imageUrls = new [] { "foo.png", "bar.png", "foobar.png" };
// ...
Random r = new Random();
image.BackImageUrl = imageUrls[r.Next(imageUrls.Length)];
```

**Update** (still not getting the issue, though)

Only set a certain image if the generated random number is 1:

```
int i = r.Next(1, 5); // random (1-4)

Cache[diceKey] = i; 

if (i == 1)
{
  image.BackImageUrl = "Images/black.png";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need display my image when random number is 1 else do not display it.   is this way correct: if (r.Next(1, 2) == 1 )